# Drawing a chat bubble similar to this image - Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am trying to create a chat bubble for one of my android project. I have tried creating the bubble using 9-patch images but couldn't create one successfully. Can someone help me in creating a custom view for the same.

[image]

Here is the 9 patch image that i used
[image]

and here is my 9 patch implementation. the arrow in the image is not crisp

[image]

Comment: Did you face any specific problem while creating 9-patch image? 9-patch should work fine.

Comment: @Abhi The arrow in the image didn't scale properly for different screen sizes

Comment: Please include that information in the question and show your attempt at the 9patch

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of it?

Comment: @AbhishekV I have added the screenshot of the 9 patch implementation

Comment: You could push in the right edge and pull out the "arrow" a bit, no?

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry, i couldnt get u

Comment: Move the right edge of your bubble border over so the "arrow" of the chat is more defined

Comment: I think arrow is not properly drawn in the base image itself. It's way too small. Have look at telegram msg bubble background for the reference : https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/dev/TMessagesProj/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/msg_out.9.png

Comment: @AbhishekV even the telegram bubble produces a blurry image http://prntscr.com/ccxenr

Comment: Edited the link. Try the latest one

Comment: Still the image looks blurry but in the telegram app the image is very clear. 
http://prntscr.com/ccxhtr

Comment: You can check the source of telegram where exactly that image is being used..it"s open source :)

Comment: Yup going through it :D

Comment: It looks fine to me in my sample app though. http://tinypic.com/r/2ajul5j/9

Comment: @AbhishekV can u share me your sample?

Comment: there is nothing much in sample app..I just put the 9patch image in `drawable-xhdpi` folder and set it as background to the `TextView` in XML.